# SQL Select query for selecting values from a particular column having continuous same value(true/false) for another column for last 7 days

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to select all values from column '**Name**' where value in 'Result' column is continuous 'Pass' for last 7 days for a particular 'Environment'.

Table structure is as following:

| Name | Result | Timestamp | Environment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Pass | July 02, 2022, 1:34 AM | UAT |
| PQR | Pass | July 02, 2022, 1:34 AM | UAT |
| XYZ | Pass | July 02, 2022, 1:34 AM | UAT |
| ABC | Fail | June 30, 2022, 1:34 AM | Dev |
| ABC | Pass | June 30, 2022, 1:34 AM | UAT |
| XYZ | Fail | June 30, 2022, 1:34 AM | UAT |
| ABC | Fail | June 21, 2022, 1:34 AM | UAT |

In this case, I will get 'ABC' and 'PQR' as response for 'Environment' UAT, as XYZ failed in last 7 days.

Comment: Last 7 days mean? Last 7 days from today?

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, 7 days from today.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT name,environment
FROM t 
WHERE timestamp::date >= CURRENT_DATE-7
GROUP BY name,environment
HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE result = 'Fail' OR result IS NULL) = 0;

 name | environment 
------+-------------
 ABC  | UAT
 PQR  | UAT
(2 rows)
```

Basically you list `name`and `environment`, and then count how many records match the criteria you want to exclude, namely `result = 'Fail'` within the last 7 days (from current date). Those with count 0 are the records you're looking for.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b43408e2d0cf10e76d17330a9b34006f)

Comment: This will return also name+ environment never tested in the required period. My guess is OP wants positive testing.

Comment: @Serg thanks for the comment! You mean this? (third query): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=188e4f600653c58779d66a7dd684a831

Comment: Test it with just 2 rows `INSERT INTO t VALUES
('ABC','Pass','July 02, 2021, 1:34 AM','UAT'),
('PQR','Pass','July 02, 2022, 1:34 AM','UAT');`

Comment: @Serg it gives the same result: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=81d43e0d5a8126e7f78126d9a7be5a2d most likely I did not understand your point :-D

Comment: Exactly, it returns 2 rows. My guess is OP wants only ABC row because PQR has no rows in the required period at all.

Comment: @Serg oh I see.. so beleve this is the fix you're mentioning: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2dc7b92985776b51e697bba99255883d